# How to FTP particular Folder ? ??

Tags: unix

I am using Unix Language for scripting. I am in need of Unix Commands for FTP particular folder & its contents.

Main Folder Contains many Sub-folders & Sub-folder contains many files inside.
I need to FTP Main folder (with its Sub-folders & it's contents) to Local server using Unix Language.

Or Suggest Command to FTP Particular & its contents to another Server in **Sun OS**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use mget: it allows you to transfer an entire directory with all subdirectories.

Use the "-s" option of ftp: it allows you to store all FTP commands in a script (login, change directory, mget contents).